# Set property  of User Controls to be able to popup select project file path

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

[image]

Is is possible to set property of User Controls to be able to browse file path within project as in the figure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the [UrlEditor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.design.urleditor.aspx).

Basically, you will declare your property like this :

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string YourProp
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["YourProp"];          
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["YourProp"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. This can't be used with automatic property ?
2. Should it works after rebuild, or do i need to perform a further step ?

Comment: 1. actually, the body of getter and setter are not important... you can store the value in the viewstate as I show you, or you can use auto property... it depends on your need. The important part is the attribute, which is used by the designer (the designer only manages signatures, not body of properties)

Comment: 2. no further steps if you are in the same project. If the control is defined in a separate assembly, you may have to close the web form or maybe even Visual Studio (didn't try for a long)